# E-mail not getting sent in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code in a PHP file.

```
 $to = $row['EmailID'];
 $subject = "XYZ";
 $message = "yes!!!!";
 $from = "pallav123goyal@gmail.com";
 if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,"From:" . $from))
   {
echo "Confirmation E-mail couldn't be sent to " . $row['EmailID'] . "<br>";
   }
 else
     {
     echo "Confirmation E-mail sent to " . $row['EmailID'] . "<br>";
     }
 }
```

On running the code, the else part of the above code is executed as evident from its output. But no e-mail gets sent to $row['EmailID'] (which is a valid email ID) What could be the error?

Comment: Are you running on your localhost? This often results in no error, but still not sending an email.

Comment: If u are on windows : Did u specify a smtp server in your php.ini ?

Comment: The `mail` function only delivers the eMail to your SMTP server. It doesn't send the eMail as such. Your SMTP does that. So make sure you have your SMTP configured correctly.

Comment: I am using linux. How do I check my SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
<?php
$to =$row['EmailID'];
$subject ="XYZ";
$txt ="yes!!!!";
$headers = "From: pallav123goyal@gmail.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a problem with your sendmail (assuming you are running the code on a linux system) configuration and not with the code per se. Try to use PEAR mail and specify an external SMTP server (e.g. gmail).

Comment: How do I specify the SMTP?

Comment: Have a look here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php and here http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm